# Console logging not happening in setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using this [repository](https://github.com/TradingPal/react-native-highcharts) and copying the exact example given in the documentation

I was just playing around and tried doing a *console log* here

```
var conf = {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function() {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function() {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.random(); //Pass data here which comes from socket
                        console.log("this is value of series", series)
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 2000);
                }
            }
        },
```

This is my `console.log` in above code snippet

```
console.log("this is value of series", series)
```

Now, when I check my logs, I can't see it (the above log, not even once)

**[Question:]** Why could this be happening? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe it's never being called..?

Comment: do you have the remote debugger open and connected?

Comment: @user2864740 probably Yes! It isn't being called but then why is it not being called?

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak Yes?

Comment: If it's not being called, the the question is "why is the timer callback not being called?" (nothing to do with `console.log`, btw) which leads to a question "is the timer callback setup?" - and thus a **Hypothesis**: "load is not being called and/or and exception is thrown before the timer is created". Test the hypothesis.

Comment: @user2864740 Timer callback is being called again after the given interval, it isn't just logging the statement.

Comment: Then it *is* being called.. as opposed to "..It *isn't* being called.."; also, how is it known to be called? (The side-effect would be updates to series.. but such side-effect/observation was *not claimed* - questions should provide relevant details, *including justification of assumptions*.)

Comment: @user2864740 Okay, but then again it isn't logging

Comment: The event was not dispatched by highcharts, did you actually *create* the chart, i.e., bind to the DOM, passing an element selector and this config?? `Highcharts.chart()`

Comment: I'm voting to close because of waffling between "is called" and "isn't called", without corresponding evidence to either case. It is or it isn't being called, and such hypothesis can be tested without relying on the actual result of calling it.

Comment: To further complicate matters the question/title *assumes* that "not working" is a result of setInterval, without claiming validation of such assertion with a working SSCCE without the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `load` method manually. It should either throw error or do actual logging.

I guess there are only two things that can go wrong with your code:

1. `load` is simply not called
2. `load` is called, but maybe some error occured before `console.log`, and also there is some wrapping `try .. catch` that swallows the error

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that a Chart was *not* initialized, else the `load` event would've been dispatched by Highcharts:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', { ... });
```

Since you're following [this](https://github.com/TradingPal/react-native-highcharts) example, `ChartView` component should've taken care of Chart initialization for you, so you likely didn't import things correctly or have an error:

1. make sure you have **zero** typescript compiler errors (missing imports, etc).
2. make sure you installed `package.json` dependencies
3. make sure there is **zero** run-time errors (check `console.log`)
4. make sure you are not looking at a cached version of your app; ensure a 200 status code *not* a 304.